# How to animate the blur value of an image over some time period in iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I want to animate an image  from 0 gaussian blur to a 25 pixel blur value over some time period, let's say 0.5 sec. I am totally stuck with this. Any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it seems like it would be ideal to gradually adjust the blur radius from 0 to 25, that's probably too computationally intensive. On an iPhone 5, blurring 320x568 image once with 25px radius took 600 msec using `CIGaussianBlur` filter. It took 150 msec using `UIImage+ImageEffects` (on [WWDC 2013 downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013)) which uses [vImage high-performance image processing framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001001). Clearly trying to repeatedly blur an image over 0.5 seconds would be untenable.

But, instead, just replace the image with a blurred image using `transitionWithView` with cross dissolve:

```
UIImage *blurImage = [self blur:imageView.image radius:25];

[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    imageView.image = blurImage;
} completion:nil];
```

This yields a smooth and remarkably convincing approximation of the transition you describe.

---

This technique appears to work with iOS 8 `UIBlurEffect` on `UIVisualEffectView`, too:

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds;

[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    [imageView addSubview:visualEffectView];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: I found your first to first technique to be useful for me.